# C++ macro (min max) not working properly

Tags: c++, macros

Why doesn't the following code work? It prints INT_MAX. But if I uncomment the two lines in the inner for loop, then it works fine (prints 2). I can't combine the two macros like that? Not sure if further detail is needed...pretty self explanatory.

Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>

using namespace std;

#define min(a,b) a<b?a:b
#define max(a,b) a>b?a:b

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int N = 100;
    int *drop = new int[N+1];
    drop[0] = 0; drop[1] = 1; drop[2] = 1;
    for(int i=3; i<=N; i++)
    {
        drop[i] = INT_MAX;
        for(int start=1; start<=i; start++)
        {
            drop[i] = min(drop[i], max(start, drop[i-start]+1));
            //int x = max(start, drop[i-start]+1);
            //drop[i] = min(drop[i], x);
        }
    }
    cout<<drop[3]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use the library functions so you don't allow `min(35, "frog")`, which is allowed because you used a macro and macros don't have type checking.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put brackets around the terms in your macros:

```
#define min(a,b) ((a)<(b)?(a):(b))
#define max(a,b) ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))
```

As it is, this:

```
drop[i] = min(drop[i], max(start, drop[i-start]+1));
```

is expanding to this (without brackets):

```
drop[i] < start > drop[i-start]+1 ? start: drop[i-start]+1 ? drop[i] : start > drop[i-start]+1 ? start: drop[i-start]+1;
```

which may not evaluate in the order you intend. Using brackets enforces the correct order of operations.

As noted in the comments, you shouldn't use macros with expressions that have side effects if the macro arguments are evaluated more than once.

Comment: That is still *very* wrong: expressions such as `min(x++,y)` would cause inadvertent double increment of `x`. See my answer in 2 min.

Comment: @Michael You shouldn't use macros with expressions that have side effects. That's arguably a problem with the use of the macro rather than the macro itself. In OP's example the expressions passed to the macro do not have side effects.

Comment: @Michael: Just because macros can be dangerous does not mean they are wrong. You are simply supposed to know what you are doing.

Answer (score 9):

C++ already has `std::min` and `std::max` defined in `<algorithm>`. You can change your code to a pure C++ version

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int N = 100;
    int * drop = new int[N + 1];
    drop[0] = 0;
    drop[1] = drop[2] = 1;
    for (int i = 3; i <= N; ++i) {
        drop[i] = numeric_limits<int>::max();    // <limits>
        for(int start = 1; start <= i; ++start)
            drop[i] = min(drop[i], max(start, drop[i - start] + 1));    // <algorithm>
    }
    cout << drop[3] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Marked samgak's response as answer as it solved my confusion, but I suppose I should be using the built in stuff. But what on earth is bits/stdc++.h...you said it's in <algorithm> but included something else altogether. I don't use C++ at all clearly.

Comment: @shek bits/stdc++ is a header that includes all headers in c++. But, dont worry i'll edit it.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks. Was just curious about the bits/stdc++.h

Answer (score 8):

Rather than an answer, it's a plead to all developers out there: please don't use macros like that. C++ offers template functions for these purposes. Remember that macros just substitute parameters rather than pre-evaluating them. Even if you add parentheses as samgak explained, this only fixes a half of the problem. Consider code like this:

```
int x = 5;
int y = max(++x, 0);
```

The caller would expect `x=6` and `y=6` after that; however the macro will get expended into

```
int y = (++x > 0)? ++x : 0;
```

causing `x=7` and `y=7`.

Comment: The C++ language also allows for *inline* functions too.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: yes, a proper solution would be something like `template<type T> inline T max(T x, T y) { return x > y? x : y; }` Even better solution would be to use `std::max`. Anything but a macro.

Comment: Functions do not provide lazy evaluation semantics. Macros can, which is why macros cannot be replaced by functions. At least not so simply.

Comment: @AnT: Do you mean macros like this: `#define LOG(string)  (logging && log(string))` (from http://dlang.org/lazy-evaluation.html)? And is speed the only reason someone would like to use lazy evaluation in C/C++ instead of a strict evaluation? It's interesting.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, speed is not a small thing: for production software speed may be a difference between success and failure. Besides that, lazy evaluation value is not limited to speed. Consider things like `if( ptr != NULL && *ptr != '\n') {...}` which would work as desired with lazy evaluation, but may cause a segfault if `&&` was't lazy.